# How to search text in specific documents and not all documents in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

First I created index for my data:

```
db.stores.find( { $text: { $search: "java coffee shop" } } )
```

and here is the code for searching text inside the indexed field.

```
db.stores.find( { $text: { $search: "shop" } } )
```

but the problem is it searches the whole documents in my collection for the word "shop", and I want to limit its explore to some specific documents based on for example their id.
In other words, I want to just search the word "shop" through documents in my collection that
the value of their Occupation field is equal to "Z1";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add the other field like this:

`db.stores.find( { occupation: "Z1", $text: { $search: "shop" } } )`